# How to disable Vary header in bitnami wordpress

Tags: wordpress, header, bitnami, vary

Which version of the application are you using?:
WordPress 4.8.2

Please choose how you got the application: Installer (Windows, Linux, macOS), cloud image (AWS, GCE, Azure, ...) or VM (VMDK, VBOX): 
google cloud

Have you installed any plugin or modified any configuration file?: 
wp super cache

Describe here your question/suggestion/issue (expected and actual results):

CDN can not hit my resource on edge server because of the vary header setting.

how to disable the vary:cookie?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can unset the header in the `/installdir/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf`
 file by adding the following:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset Vary
</IfModule>
```

Hope it helps,

Michiel D'Hont

Comment: hi michiel , it works , but how can i keep the " Accept-Encoding" while  throwing "cookies" away

Answer (score 0):

You could add it in the following way:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header unset Vary
 Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</IfModule>
```